# Alternative to Intermediate-macroeconomics book by Mankiw

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request

Please suggest a good alternative to intermediate macroeconomics by Mankiw. A book with better teaching and which develops better understanding but at a similar level in terms of difficulty. I personally do not like mankiw's book. I can understand concepts at superficial level but do not get in depth understanding.

Comment: I would like recommend Steven Williamson's Macroeconomics. It's roughly at the same level as Mankiw's book, but more centers on developing basic ideas around RBC and its extensions.

Comment: When I read them, I found Mankiw's books to be quite adequate. What, in your opinion, is missing for "in depth understanding"? I don't think economics is a subject that you can gain an "understanding of" to the same "depth" as, for example, Newtonian mechanics. If that is your expectation you will have to develop your own much-improved version of economics ;)

Comment: There seems to be controversy (and walkouts during his class) regarding Mankiw's 10 Principles.  @MettaWorldPeace (or anyone else), is there a book that would have a contrasting worldview, but equal in quality?  A non keynesian or marxist view might fit.

Comment: Hal R Varian's book on Intermediate economics is what I used, and it was pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend Blanchard's Macroeconomics, especially for the short and medium run.
Another book to look at, especially for the long run and growth is Burda and Wyplosz (2012)

Answer (score 1):

A great (more technical but still easily accessible) intermediate Macro book is "Macroeconomic Theory and Policy" by David Andolfatto